# Expo assets not showing after build in android device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, assets

Im using expo `~49.0.11` and expo-asset `^8.10.1`, While running on development mode assets are displaying but after the build assets are not displaying in,

```
const [assets] = useAssets([require("../assets/package.png")]);

// JSX
{
 Array.isArray(assets) && assets.length ? (
  <Image
    style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
    source={assets[0].localUri}
  />
 ) : null
}
```

Expected

[image]

But the result is

[image]